# Websocket server not initialising on nest.js server

Tags: javascript, websocket, server, socket.io, nestjs

```
import { WebSocketGateway, OnGatewayInit, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(7070, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*'
  }
})
export class LivechatGateway implements OnGatewayInit {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;
  
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('LivechatGateway');

  constructor() {
    this.logger.log('WebSocketGateway constructor called.');
  }

  onModuleInit() {
    console.log('WebSocketGateway initialized via OnModuleInit.');
    this.logger.log('WebSocketGateway initialized via OnModuleInit.');
  }

  afterInit() {
    this.logger.log('WebSocket server initialized');
    console.log('WebSocket server initialized');
  }

  handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: any) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why both the constructor() and onModuleInit() would both log, but the afterInit would not. I have run this on another backend, and it worked fine, it is just this backend that is not working. What could be interfering with the initialisation of the websocket server?

I tried to spin up a websocket server, but I am not seeing the afterInit logs, suggesting the server is not successfully starting.

Comment: solved by upgrading nest.js to v10